# Jenkins could not locate pom.xml of the project

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a created a job for mavenized github project. When I build it, I am getting the error as unable to locate pom.xml under jenkins_dir/workspace/build_name. But when I look into Jenkins directory I could see that Jenkins has cloned the project from GitHub to it's workspace under jenkins_dir/workspace/build name/project name/pom.xml but it is looking for pom in jenkins_dir/workspace/build name. Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I think your configuration is a little off.  Assuming your job type is a Maven Project, and given you have said Jenkins is currently looking for the pom file in

```
jenkins_dir/workspace/build name
```

you should change the Root POM field to

```
"project name/pom.xml"
```

Paths in Jenkins are workspace-relative.